# SPFx - Get selected row data from DetailsList office-ui-fabric-react control

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am developing the SPFX webpart using react class components and wanted to get the selected row data from DetailsList office-ui-fabric-react control.I am stuck with implementation of selection property in the DetailsList control. Can you please help me in the Selection property implementation?

```
    export default class ProviderWebPartDemo extends React.Component<IProviderWebPartDemoProps, IProviderWebPartDemoState> {
  private _selection: ISelection<IObjectWithKey>;

  private _onItemsSelectionChanged = () => {
    
    this.props.onDepartmentSelected(this._selection.getSelection()[0] as IDepartment);
    
    this.setState({
      Department: (this._selection.getSelection()[0] as IDepartment)
    });

    
  }
  
  constructor(props: IProviderWebPartDemoProps, state: IProviderWebPartDemoState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
      Department: {
        Id: 0,
        Title: ""
      },
      Deparments: []
    });
    this._selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: this._onItemsSelectionChanged,
    });  

   
  }

<DetailsList
      items={ this.state.Deparments}
      columns={ _departmentListColumns }
      setKey='Id'
      checkboxVisibility={ CheckboxVisibility.always}
      selectionMode={ SelectionMode.single}
      layoutMode={ DetailsListLayoutMode.fixedColumns }
      compact={ true }
      selection={this._selection }                                        
  />
```

[I am stuck with implementation of selection property in the DetailsList control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3RPn.png)

The above code throwing following error "Type 'Selection' is missing the following properties from type 'ISelection': count, mode, canSelectItem, setChangeEvents, and 18 more"